# How to configure Spring Boot to use BOTH Vault and properties file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault

I have setup my Spring Boot application to read configuration from a HashiCorp Vaults instance. I have a "bootstrap.yml" with the connection + authentication information for Vaults. However, I only want to use Vaults for sensitive information, and prefer to maintain the use of "application.properties" for other configuration.  Is it possible to use both?

This is the error I'm getting on application startup:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.findOrder(OrderComparator.java:142) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.findOrder(AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.java:65) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.getOrder(OrderComparator.java:125) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.getOrder(OrderComparator.java:113) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.doCompare(OrderComparator.java:82) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.compare(OrderComparator.java:68) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:360) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:220) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1462) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.asUnmodifiableOrderedSet(SpringApplication.java:1344) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getListeners(SpringApplication.java:1253) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextLoaded(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextLoaded(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:331) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.Application.main(Application.java:15) [classes/:na]
```

This is an extract from the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried, but the application fails to run, seemingly because it can't read certain properties.